# Kotlin arrow-kt missing flatMap on Validated and ValidatedNel

Tags: validation, kotlin, arrow-kt

I am really struggeling with the Validated types of the arrow library.

What I don't get is: why is there no `flatMap` or `flatten` when working with Validated?

I am coming from the "Either world" where this is no issue at all. But I need multiple errors combined, so my core validation type is `ValidatedNel<Error, Data>` in the end.

In my code example, I have a function that produces an Either - I use these low-level steps to either create an element I need or an error.

But to do a correct validation with all accumulated errors combined, I sooner or later need `ValidatedNel` types.

```
fun readData(): Either<Error, DataA> = ...
fun DataA.validate(): ValidatedNel<Error, DataB> = ...

[...]
// here I need to fold to get my one Error to a Nel and to process the data to another type - this looks so ugly!
val validated = readData().fold( { it.invalidNel() }, DataA::validate)
```

What I instead would like to have is:

```
fun readData(): ValidatedNel<Error, DataA> = ...

// ...
val validated = readData.flatMap(DataA::validate)
```

I simply don't understand why the Validation types do not support a simple operation like flatMap.

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Validation only requires `Applicative` and `Monoid`; it does not require `Monad`.  Or, plainly speaking: things that validate data can occur in any order (`Applicative`) and multiple validations accumulate errors, usually by concatenating lists of errors (`Monoid`).  Validations are usually not dependent on each other or require a specific sequence of computations (`Monad`).

Dependent validations are probably better expressed as an `Either` chain then converted to a `Validation` after the chain completes.

The Scala Cats library has a good explanation here: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html