# is ValidatedNel arrow-kt in v1.0 still an Applicative (Functor)?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I understand that in previous versions of Arrow-Kt was an instance of the Applicative typeclass. In the current version 1.0.x, most typeclasses are no longer present/visible (to make the library more accessible, I presume?).

There are some excellent explanations why an error accumulating Validation data type can't be a Monad, for instance [Haskell 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539650/why-can-accvalidation-not-have-a-monad-instance) and [Haskell 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844042/how-could-we-know-that-an-applicative-cant-be-a-monad) and also [Scalaz, Cats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174323/why-would-validation-break-the-monad-laws) or [arrow-kt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57294629/kotlin-arrow-kt-missing-flatmap-on-validated-and-validatednel). [Hoogle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) also states that

```
Furthermore, the Monad and Applicative operations should relate as follows:
pure = return
m1 <*> m2 = m1 >>= (x1 -> m2 >>= (x2 -> return (x1 x2)))
```

My problem is that I can't see an instance of the Applicative Functor instance in the current implementation of Validated in arrow-kt. More precisely, I don't see an `ap` function anywhere:

```hs
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

my intuition tells me that the `zip` function behaves somewhat similar to a `map`/`ap` composition

Haskell/Purescript:

```hs
Person <$> validateName first <*> validateName last <*> validateAge age
```

Kotlin with arrow-kt:

```kotlin
validateName(first).zip(validateName(last), validateAge(age), ::Person)
```

is `zip` an `ap` in disguise? Anything else I might be missing in my reasoning?

Comment: You are correct, zip is map in disquise. It was renamed to be more inline with the kotlin standard library naming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @LordRaydenMK has already mentioned in a comment `zip` is `ap` in disguise to be more in line with the Kotlin Standard Library.

Another strong reason for not having `ap` in Kotlin is because currying is not 1st class supported by Kotlin as it is in Haskell, and we cannot define multiple parameter lists like in Scala. So far that reason `ap` is actually quite cumbersome to use, and not user-friendly at all.

So for the sake of user-friendliness, being more idiomatic in Kotlin and decreasing the learning curve Arrow decided to remove `ap` and offer `zip` instead.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation! Just to make sure, I understand it correctly, I tried to implement `ap` by using the existing `zip` function:

```kotlin
fun <E, A, B> ValidatedNel<E, (A) -> B>.ap(fa: ValidatedNel<E, A>): ValidatedNel<E, B> = zip(fa) { f, a -> f(a) }
```

it works surprisingly well, even on curried functions

```kotlin
fun add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
 ::add.curried().validNel().ap(42.validNel()).ap(5.validNel())
```

But I see your point why this is not idiomatic Kotlin ;-)

Comment: Chris from the future here. There is another great explanation why zip and ap are equivalent and sufficient to define a datatype as an Applicative (besides the need of a proper type constructor).

Instead of implementing `ap`, you could also implement `liftA2` which has the following type signature: 

```
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```. 

It converts a binary function to a function where all its arguments and return type are lifted inside an applicative. It is also basically just the `zip` function with flipped arguments.